# Is weed (marijuana) forbidden?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

As far as I know, there is no statement in Quaran or in Hadith clearly taking position about consumption of weed.

My question is: is weed forbidden (haram) or allowed (halal), and the most important, why?